# PT4115, where should I put output capacitor?

Tags: ripple-current

The [PT4115E datasheet](http://www.micro-bridge.com/data/CRpowtech/PT4115E.pdf) states:

> Peak to peak ripple current in the
>   LED(s) can be reduced below 30% of the average
>   current, if required, by adding a capacitor across
>   the LED(s).

[image: PT4115E schematic with AC 12-24V]

Can you confirm that "across the leds" is:

- from : between `Rs` and `led`
- to : between `led` and `L`

?

Comment: "across" means in parallel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is pretty straight forward. Exactly in parallel with the LEDs
[image]

- Please check whether adding the capacitor has an impact on the dimming frequencies and startup delay based on your end application.